# Parsing all integers in a string after the character from CSV with Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, csv

I've written a mini-script to go through and remove the hash tag and all of the integer string. Below, is the data:

```
Test #456
Test #783
Test #990
Test #123
Test #560
Test #983
Test #195
```

The data is in CSV format and I'm trying to migrate the results into another CSV (although I'm open to better ideas). Here is the code I have written:

```
reader = open('testin.csv', "r")
lines = reader.read().split('#'[0].rstrip() + '/n')
reader.close()

writer = open('testout.csv', "w")
for line in set(lines):
    writer.write(line + "\n")
writer.close()

print "Complete"
```

The script just moves the data unchanged.

Comment: That's not a csv format. CSV stands for "Comma Separated Values": each row has multiple values, separated by a delimiter (typically a comma, hence the name).

Comment: Was pretty late, I meant \ !! By CSV I meant that the data is stored in a single column in a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a regex substitution:

```
import re

with open('testin.csv', 'r') as reader:
    lines = [re.sub(r' *#\d+', '', line.strip()) for line in reader]

with open('testout.csv', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
with open('testin.csv) as inf, open('testout.csv', 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
         parts = line.split('#')
         leftpart = parts[0].rstrip()
         outf.write(leftpart + '\n')
```

You have to split each line, not the whole file. You also have to take [0] on the result of split, not on the '#' that you pass to it, because '#'[0] is just '#'. And you want to call rstrip on the result of that. If it's too complicated to understand all on one line, write it on multiple lines.

This might not be what you want, because you keep talking about CSV files, which have multiple values per line, and you also talk about parsing integers rather than just ignoring them. So maybe you wanted this:

```
import csv
with open('testin.csv) as inf, open('testout.csv', 'w') as outf:
    w = csv.writer(outf)
    for line in inf:
         parts = line.split('#')
         leftpart = parts[0].rstrip()
         rightpart = parts[1].rstrip()
         intvalue = int(rightpart)
         # do something with intvalue?
         w.writerow(leftpart, str(intvalue))
```

This is a little silly--I'm just parsing the integer to turn it right back into the same string, and ultimately you could do the same thing just by replacing each ' #' with a ','. But it hopefully gives you an idea of how to write whatever code you're actually trying to write.